# How do you get files used with "Open With" on Mac in Java?

Tags: java, macos, .app, open-with

I've compiled my Java program into the Mac's `.app` format using the `javapackager` command. How do I get the files that a user will open my program with using the system's "Open With" context menu command?

For example, if I had a file `MyFile.txt` on the desktop and I right clicked and opened it with my program, how do I access `MyFile.txt`?

Comment: There is a the same question on `apple.stackexchange`, so I can't mark it as a duplicate.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15030/how-can-i-add-a-new-application-to-the-open-with-menu

Comment: That question is how to add it to the "Open with" menu. I'm asking after it has been added to the menu, how do you access the file that was right clicked on.

Comment: Have you checked the parameters ? The path is likely to be here

Comment: Nothing is passed to the main() method.

Answer (score 0):

I think file associations was what I was looking for  (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/selfContainedApps/fileassociation.html). Thanks to Reddit user [PhantomOTOpera](https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/crfd1t/comment/ex57h3t). But I still haven't managed to figure out how to get the file.